# Telebot загрузка файлов

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
def load():
    file_name = message.document.file_name
    file_id_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_id_info.file_path)
    ...
    new_file = open(file_name, 'wb')
    new_file.write(downloaded_file)
    new_file.close()
```

Пишу бота под телеграмм, что-то типа облачного хранилища. Задача бота сохранить файл, который ему отправили. Можно даже сказать, что он это делает, но! Файл в итоге пустой. Может вы знаете, в чём проблема?

Answer (score 3):

```
   # получить основную информацию о файле и подготовить его к загрузке
   file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
   downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

   # определяем путь загрузки с именем файла
   src = 'C:/Python/Project/tg_bot/files/received/' + message.document.file_name;

   # открываем файл для записи
   with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
        # записываем данные в файл
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)
```

Comment: ответ исправлен